# Load/Include a Id element of a page to a div

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page `Index.php`, where when I clicked a button(`#incoming`) a div which has an id of `wrapperc4` will call an div id element from another page.

```
 $('#incoming').click(function() {
  $('#wrapperc4').load('IncomingRecords.php #example2');

});
```

so my code is like this. Im in `Index.php` the button is the `#incoming` when click the `#wrapperc4` div will change its content from `#example2` id which is from `IncomingRecords.php`.

but it doesn't work. does any have an idea how to properly execute this? Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Apparently it should work. Check for spelling and check your debug window output. Also try to give some fiddle for us to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend doing is making use of **partials**. Split the content that you want to `load()` into a page by itself, so that you can import the page in its entirity on the jQuery side. Then you can simply make use of PHP's **[`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)** function to include the partial are the desired point on the existing `IncomingRecords.php` page.

This would be the structure:

`example2.php`:

```
<div id='example2'>Example 2</div>
```

`IncomingRecords.php`

```
<?php

echo "<div id='example1'>Example 1</div>";
include('partials/example2.php'); // Import the DIV from `example2.php`
echo "<div id='example3'>Example 3</div>";
```

`index.php`:

```
$('#incoming').click(function() {
 $('#wrapperc4').load('partials/example2.php');
});
```

Hope this helps! :)